# How to solve API Keys owner for Amazon API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch, api-key

I use AWS API Gateway for a REST API. I'd like to solve how to connect API Key to its owner user. For example when I found a incorrect or peculiar API request from Cloudwatch I will look at an API Key used for this request. Now I have to connect that API Key with its owner.
I have read AWS CLI references but can't find good CLI command combination to find an user for a specific API Key.
API Keys information can be asked with this command:

```
aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key keyabc123_ --profile myProfileabc
```

but how to continue from here with CLI and without looking from the console?

Comment: API Key are not AWS user based. They can be used by anyone, unless you create an API key for every AWS user you have (which is limited to 10,000). Unless you talked about aws secret key and aws key id...?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I have AWS Developer portal where new user gets a new API Key when registration to portal is done. Registration needs a verified email Address. So I don't have one person to connect, but at least an email address which could be used by team of developers or something like that.
In developer portal I can sign in as an admin and then sort user list by API Key to get that email. 
I'd like to write script that returns this information without signing into portal.